# SearchBar in iOS NavigationBar slightly moves down upon touch

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, google-places-autocomplete

I have a search bar I am placing inside of the navigation bar for Google Place AutoComplete. It shows up fine when it appears, but when you tap inside of it, it moves down slightly and stays there even if you hit cancel, until you set the titleView to nil and back again, then it resets. Here is the relevant code called in my viewDidLoad method:

```
resultsViewController = GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()
    resultsViewController?.delegate = self

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsViewController)
    searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = resultsViewController
    searchController?.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    navigationItem.titleView = nil
```

Then when need I set it like so:

```
navigationItem.titleView = searchController?.searchBar
```

[image: when search bar first loads]
[image: after tapping search bar]

Comment: Try putting different background colors on different elements to figure out if something is taller than you’d expect.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try This:

```
    searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRect(center: CGPoint(x: 15,y: 10), size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
    let vu = UIView(frame: CGRect(center: .zero, size: CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width - 10, height: 40)))
    
    vu.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
    vu.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    
    navigationItem.titleView = vu
```

> set frames according to your need